# Header file error: incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c, struct, header-files, keil

This is my header file:

```
typedef int* Arg;   
typedef int* Args[];
typedef int** ArgsList[];

typedef int (*ProcessStart)(Args);

typedef struct PCBEntry{

    ProcessStart proc;
    Args args;
    int pid;
    int curr_proc;
    int sched_info;
    int pc;

} PCBEntry;
```

I get the error on the `Args args`line in the struct and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you defined `Args` as `int *[]`, the member `args` is effectively declared as

```
int *args[];
```

This is a flexible array member, and they are only allowed at the end of a structure.

If you meant to imply that `Args` was a pointer (in the same vein as `char **argv`), declare it as a pointer:

```
typedef int **Args;
```

Comment: "You can't put a "variable-sized array" in a struct" - except if you have a C99 compiler and you put the variable sized array to the end of the struct.

Comment: @H2CO3 Strictly, a flexible array member is not a variable length array. You can't put a VLA into a struct.

Comment: You're suggesting changing `Args` from an array type to a pointer type. That might be a good solution, but it's a big change to the structure.

Comment: `Args` isn't a VLA type. A VLA has a specified non-constant size; `Args` doesn't have a specified size at all.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments; I rewrote the answer to be clearer.

Comment: Are we sure they're only allowed at the end of a structure? C++ maybe, but I'm not sure C cares... I have structures in my projects that have flexible arrays embedded in the middle of the structure (think of a message wrapper with a header, body and tail where the body size is variable). I've used that technique many times over the years.

Comment: @KScottPiel: Pretty sure it's not legal. I'd be curious to see code like that which would compile, but I don't think it would be standard C.

Comment: This compiles for me... `  struct MyMessage
  {
   char STX;
   size_t bodyLen;
   char body[];
   char ETX;
  };
  
  struct MyMessage* test = malloc( sizeof( struct MyMessage ) + payloadLength );
  
`

Comment: @KScottPiel It's not valid C. But that doesn't oblige the compiler to reject it.

Comment: It doesn't compile with any compiler or settings I have on hand. Which one are you using?

Comment: @ nneonneo -- gcc 4.4.7 on an RHEL6 -- also just tried it with g++ 4.4.7 and it flew there as well (though you have to cast the `malloc` in g++)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
typedef int* Args[];
```

and in your structure declaration

```
Args args;
```

you would be better served to just use the first type for your structure declaration...

```
Arg args[];
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure the the first one is a legal typedef, but it's only that I've never ever done anything like that with a typedef before. My gut tells me that it's not legal and therefore `Args` is undefined and thus the error you're getting. If I apply the right-left rule to that, then `Args` is a type that is an array of pointers to int... so, maybe it's legal, but it sure reads funny to my eye.